# open() function with denied permission

Tags: c

I am trying to create a 'test.txt' file in root directory. Currently I am not a root user. my code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
    int fd;
    fd=open("/test.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC,0777);
    perror("error: ");
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

however, when I compile and execute it, I get the error:

```
error: : Permission denied
```

how can I make my code to have the permission to create a file in root directory?

P.S. I am trying to make this work so that I can use it later on to apply this method to my linux daemon program.

Comment: Your program has to be run as a user which have permission to write in the asked directory. I suggest you rethink where to place your daemon files, have a separate folder (in e.g. `/var/lib` or similar) owned by a special user created just for your daemon. That way you don't have to run the daemon as `root` and sidestep a big security risk.

Comment: you should run your program as a admin/root

Comment: @user1234 no, not really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    fd=open("/test.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR|O_TRUNC,0777);
```

In this line specify path correctly.(i.e) It is current working directory means, keep (dot) `.` before `/` like`./test.txt`